# How to assign a name to intermediate pattern of a List?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

This code don't compile, what am I doing wrong? is it possible to do it?
How can I pattern match a list with at least 2 elements, and have the pattern have a variable for the tail (meaning `y :: _`)

I know it's possible desugaring the `::` or with a simple `if`. But without desugaring and without if... it's possible?

```
val list:List[Int] = ...
list match {
  case x :: tail@(y:: _) => 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if this code works for you:

```
list match {
  case x :: (tail@(y :: _)) =>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use another variable to hold the second element:

```
list match {
  case x :: y :: _ =>
}
```

This will only match a list with at least two elements, will bind `x` to the first element, `y` to the second element and ignore the rest.

If you need to just ensure the remainder of the list is at least 1 long, then

```
list match {
  case x :: y if y.size > 0 =>
}
```

will do the job.

Comment: I want to match y :: _ in a variable that contains a list with y and the rest

Comment: I wanted the other solution as I also wanted to have the head of the tail in another variable. I also explicitly asked about a solution without desugaring nor ifs